# CRM 2011 odd behavior of a simple workflow

Tags: triggers, dynamics-crm, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, assign

I have a simple workflow that re-assigns contact to an API user when the country is equal to 'France'. This workflow is triggered on Create, On Change in field (Country) and on Demand. Scope is set to Organization level.

This workflow fires off for some contacts and not for others. So in my report, I can see that it had re-assigned x number of contacts but has missed a few contacts all together. These few missed contacts do meet the criteria and should have been picked up by the workflow. To confirm this, I ran the workflow on some of these missed out contacts manually. and it worked.

My question is, why did this workflow didn't pick up these contacts? as I said, the criteria are quite simple, if country equal to France, re-assign. I found no difference in the contacts that got moved and those that didn't. Same owner, same business unit and same created on date etc. (also to confirm, the contacts I compared were both newly created contacts so the wf should have triggered on Creation)

Comment: Have you checked the system jobs to see what it says? It might tell you if something failed, or if it was unsuccessful. What you can also do is check the event log on the async server around the same time of the system job and this might give you more info too.

Comment: thank you for your reply. My WF log was set to auto delete on completion, Which I have changed now. To back my fear, I can see that the workflow triggered for some 95% of newly created contacts but missed out a small 5% of contacts. This was done by running a simple query against AsyncOperation table in DB vs count of new contacts in Contact table. The async service don't show any down time or over use of CPU either. When I click on these newly created contacts, I can see the list of workflows that ran for that contact. Again for a small number it is missing, not just this one WF but all .

Comment: Have you enabled audit trail on the Contact entity for change of country? I'd be interested to see what the audit trail looks like for the contacts that didn't trigger the workflow.

Comment: I have set number of fields enabled for audit in Contact entity and Country is one of them. Owner is also one of them so when the workflow is working, i can see in the audit trail that right after the change in Country (or create) this workflow is changing owner. But for those that is not being picked up, i can see the change in country following by no workflow. I wish I can send you the screen shot but it is confidential information that I can't share.

Comment: Can you identify one of the records that the workflow hasn't fired on.  Open that record.  Check the running workflows on the left nav of the open record.  Is this workflow present (and Waiting?) or is it not present at all?  If its waiting, open it and see why it stalled.  Is the country a required field?

Comment: Which security role has user who created/update contact when WF is not started? Can you confirm that with selected role he can start workflow?

Comment: Are the records created differently then the successful ones?  Also, are they possibly created without the country, modified to France, and then thus not firing?

Comment: What about Created On/Modified on time (as opposed to just date)?  If the workflow was temporarily deactivated during the time that the contact was created/modified, then that would be a pretty clear cause for the workflow not to have fired.  
Another cause is that the assignee may not have had permission to own these records at the time that the workflow was run (there would be a workflow in that case and it would either be in errored or waiting state with the error that the target of the assign does not have permission to own this record)